# order by date mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I used the following code to display the event details fetched from the database.

```
<form name="event_form" id="event_form" action="" method="post"  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
          <table width="765" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
          <tr>
          <td>
          <table width="765" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="results" class="fronttbl">
          <tr></tr>
          <?php
            $select = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_event`";
            $select_event = mysql_query($select);
            $select_num = mysql_num_rows($select_event);
            if($select_num > 0)
            {
                while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($select_event))
                    {
                        $feventid=$fetch['intEventid'];
                        $feventname=stripslashes(ucfirst($fetch['varEventname']));
                        $fDate=$fetch['varDate'];
                        $seperate=explode("-", $fDate );
                        $year=$seperate[0];
                        $month=$seperate[1];
                        $date=$seperate[2];
                        $fchiefguest=stripslashes(nl2br($fetch['varChiefguest']));
                        $fvenue=stripslashes($fetch['varVenue']);
                        $ftime=stripslashes($fetch['varTime']);
                        $feventdetails=stripslashes($fetch['varEventdetails']);
                        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    ?>
                    <tr>
            <td>

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%" height="30" valign="top"><strong>Name of the event:</strong></td>
    <td width="70%" height="30" valign="top"><?php echo $feventname; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Date of the event to be held:</strong></td>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><?php echo $date.'-'.$month.'-'.$year; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Time of the Event:</strong></td>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><?php echo $ftime; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Venue of the event:</strong></td>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><?php echo $fvenue; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Name of the Chief Guest:</strong></td>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><?php echo $fchiefguest; ?></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><strong>Event Details:</strong></td>
    <td height="30" valign="top"><?php echo $feventdetails; ?></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<p style="border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"></p>
            </td></tr>



    <?php               }

                }




          ?>
          </table>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
          <div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
          </form>
```

I have date field in my database table and the input will be saved like the following format `2012-03-01`.

I need my page displays the events order by recent date/month/year in the frontend. For example today's event should displayed first likewise. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sorting-rows.html) (...is that what you meant)?

Change your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl_event`
ORDER BY varDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand use this function for front end:

```
function changeFormat( $date ){
   $exp_date = explode('-', $date);
   return $exp_date[2] . '-'.$exp_date[1].'-'.$exp_date[0];
}
```

example: `echo changeFormat('2012-12-01');` will return `01-12-2012` and apply this in your while loop where you want to display your date